# Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior

Tags: swift, swiftui

I get the following error `Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior.`and do not get how to fix this issue. I already found out it should be to do something with `@state`, but I am new in swiftui.

```swift
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import Intents

struct Provider: IntentTimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: Date(), devices: [], configuration: ConfigurationIntent())
    }

    func getSnapshot(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        fetchDevices { devices in
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), devices: devices, configuration: configuration)
            completion(entry)
        }
    }

    func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<SimpleEntry>) -> ()) {
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []

        fetchDevices { devices in
            let currentDate = Date()
            for hourOffset in 0 ..< 5 {
                let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
                let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, devices: devices, configuration: configuration)
                entries.append(entry)
            }

            let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
            completion(timeline)
        }
    }

    private func fetchDevices(completion: @escaping ([Device]) -> ()) {
        // Fetch the list of Bluetooth devices and their battery state here
        let devices = [Device(name: "MacBook", batteryLevel: 80), Device(name: "AirPods", batteryLevel: 50)]
        completion(devices)
    }
}


struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let devices: [Device]
    let configuration: ConfigurationIntent
}

struct Device: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let batteryLevel: Int
}

struct BatteryWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    var devices: [Device] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        List(devices) { device in
            HStack {
                Text(device.name)
                Spacer()
                Text("\(device.batteryLevel)%")
            }.onAppear {
                self.devices = self.entry.devices
            }
        }
    }
}


@main
struct BatteryWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "BatteryWidget"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            BatteryWidgetEntryView(entry: entry, devices: [
                Device(name: "MacBook", batteryLevel: 80),
                Device(name: "AirPods", batteryLevel: 50)
            ])
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Battery Widget")
        .description("This is a Widget to show your battery state from your Bluetooth devices")
    }
}

struct BatteryWidget_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        BatteryWidgetEntryView(entry: SimpleEntry(date: Date(), devices: [], configuration: ConfigurationIntent()), devices: [
            Device(name: "MacBook", batteryLevel: 80),
            Device(name: "AirPods", batteryLevel: 50)
        ])
            .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemSmall))
    }
}
```

Comment: `@State` doesn't work in a widget, that error isn't being caused in this code. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @loremipsum I extended the example